# Gwt getCellForEvent flexTable

Tags: gwt, textbox, valuechangelistener, flextable

I`m trying to add addValueChangeHandler function to a TextBox inside a flexTable.
But when I add this code:
int rowIndex = tableImages.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
I use this method to know the current row in case of a ClickEvent.

the method is not acceptable for ValueChangeEvent,
so how can I know what is the row Index for the changed cell?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, because it needs a Cell itself, not a TextBox or event value.
What you can do, is:

1. Get the event Source via `event.getSource()`
2. Cast it to `Widget` at least (though it's safe to assume it's a textBox) `Widget sourceWidget = (Widget)event.getSource();`
3. Get the source widget's **element's** parent `sourceWidget.getElement().getParent();`

This way you'll acquire the actual `<td>` cell your textBox nested in.
Then you can getCellFormatter of your table and find the index of the cell in a loop, comparing the `<td>` element you got with the cells of your table.

Please tell me if it solved your problem

Comment: Hello Roman,
first thank you for your quick answer,
about part 3. i try this code:
 Cell cell =  (Cell) widget.getParent();
than cell is com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable.Cell;
and have error: cannot cast Widget to HTMLTable.Cell
I can see that HTMLTable is kind of Widget, but Cell is just part of HTMLTable

Comment: Can you log it's actual class to see what type is textBox parent then? Also, are you sure the Cell class you've imported is HTMLTable.Cell not some other Cell?

Comment: my TextBox is com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox.
and yes I imported this one:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable.Cell;

Comment: Sorry for misleading you: Not the type of TextBox, but the type of it's parent (which can't be cast to Cell) If you log it with toString you'll see what kind of widget it actually is

Comment: the toString returns all table xml from my ui.xml
<table border="1"><colgroup><col></colgro
etc...
<table>