# For a GWT java FlexTable how do I get the selected row number on value change

Tags: java, gwt

I want to store the GWT FlexTable row number that contains a date when that date is changed. The code is:

```
//Add change handler for the task completion date.
dateCompletion.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<java.util.Date>() {
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<java.util.Date> event) {

        //TODO currentRow = flexAwardDescription.getRowIndex();
        //Display all YM who have not completed this task.
        AsyncCallback<List<YouthMember>> callback = new YMWithoutAwardHandler<List<YouthMember>>(CubBulkAward3View.this);
        rpc.getYMWithoutAwardList(ymAwardDetails.getad_Id(), callback);
    }
});
```

I have found an answer for click event; however, not for change event.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer here: [Gwt getCellForEvent flexTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460647/gwt-getcellforevent-flextable)

There's no obvious way to do it, what you can do is

1. Get event source
2. Cast it to widget
3. Get it's Element via `.getElement()` then use `getParent()` to get Cell, and `getParent()` one more time to get row element.

You can get it's index then, comparing it to rows from rowFormatter in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The work around I came up with is to capture row number on the click event (as you must first click before you can change) and then use this row number if a change event occurs.

```
//Get the row number of the row selected to display the names below it.
                flexAwardDescription.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { 
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
                         currentRow = flexAwardDescription.getCellForEvent(event).getRowIndex();
                    } 
                }); 

                //Add change handler for the task completion date.
                dateCompletion.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<java.util.Date>() {
                    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<java.util.Date> event) {
                        //Check if this is the completion row
                        if (ymAwardDetails.getad_Description().matches("(.*)Completed:(.*)")) {
                            groupCompleted = "C";
                        }else{
                            groupCompleted = "S";
                        }
                        awardDescriptionID = ymAwardDetails.getad_Id();
                        //Display all YM who have not completed this task.
                        AsyncCallback<List<YouthMember>> callback = new YMWithoutAwardHandler<List<YouthMember>>(CubBulkAward3View.this);
                        rpc.getYMWithoutAwardList(ymAwardDetails.getad_Id(), accountId, callback);
                    }
                });
```